# Is there a better alternative to array_filter and mapping in php?

Tags: php, arrays, date-range

is there a better alternative to this code

```
$datfrm = '01/01/2000'
$datto = '01/01/2002'

$place_map = ['best' => 1, 'better' => 0.8, 'good' => 0.6];

e1 ='good,better,best' 
e2 = 'best,better,good'
 
d1='01/01/2000,01/01/2001,01/01/2002'
d2='01/01/2001,01/01/2002,01/01/2003'
    
$dresult = array_filter($dview, function($data_item) use($datfrm,$datto) {
        return $data_item >= $datfrm && $data_item <= $datto;
    });

    $eresult = array_intersect_key($efind, $dresult);
```

I'm trying a date range and it's not mapping to each other
and i want to sum the total result

Comment: Can you give some sample data to show what you are trying, also please define *better*.

Comment: Better use SQL for filtering the date ranges when getting the data from DB.

Comment: @Nigel , I've updated the code

Comment: @Rali do you mean like this?  ```(d1 <= '$datfrm' && =>'$datto')"```