# How can i add all results from a field gotten with date range in php?

Tags: php, date-range

I queried my table to get data from the date range `BETWEEN '$dat' AND '$to'`

now, i have gotten like 3 rows that contains that range..... in that data, there is a field name "cost".... how can i add all the values in costs for the rows that are displayed?

```
//range
$dat=2021-01-06;
$to=2021-01-27;


S/N     Class Date    Class Name      Cost
1       2021-01-27    PP 2011         $200
2       2021-01-09    Excel 2016      $200
3       2021-01-06    PP 2011         $200
            
Total = $200
```

i want the total to be $600 i.e summing up the result

after getting the date range.

this is what i tried

```
$total =0;
<h5>Total = <?php echo '$'.($total += $cost); ?></h5>
```

Comment: what is `$dview`?

Comment: this question looks [strangely familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62813269/is-there-a-better-alternative-to-array-filter-and-mapping-in-php)...

Comment: @MiraBeeCalifonia you should show an example of the three rows you're getting, along with the expected result you're after. Make sure that the data you provide is valid PHP syntax which we can use to help write a solution.

Comment: are you running your query in PHP to get your data or somewhere else?

Comment: @NickParsons , i have edited it to show it. thanks

Comment: @MiraBeeCalifonia but I am assuming you are running the query in PHP, and then getting the rows of the result in PHP right? Can you show what each row looks like?

Comment: @NickParsons those are the rows we got from the range, s/n 1-3

Comment: @NickParsons can you help with with this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761817/how-can-i-display-a-query-from-an-individual-data-with-mulitple-data-in-mysql-ph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this if you want to do this in PHP after getting the results from mysql

```
array_sum(array_column($your_mysql_results_array, 'cost'));
```

Comment: The variable which contains the records which are returned by your query, pass that array in array_column as first argument and in second argument pass your coloumn name for which you want the total.

Comment: post your whole source code if you don't get it still, will edit it for you :)

Comment: ```<?php
              $nos =1;
              $total=0;

                            
                            $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                             while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
                              $cost =$r['cost'];

                         
                        }
                    
                 ?>

                   <td><h5 style="text-align: right;">Total = <?php echo '$'.array_sum(array_column(mysqli_query($db, $query), 'cost')); ?></h5></td>```

Comment: $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
          // Associative array
          $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
          $total = array_sum(array_column($row, 'cost'));

Comment: since you are using while loop to iterate on each row you can do $total += $r['cost']; and once the loop completes your $total variable will contain the sum of all entries's cost.

Comment: ``` Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\pci\revenue.php on line 121

Warning: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\pci\revenue.php on line 121 ```

Comment: $nos =1;
          $total=0;
          $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
          while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
              $total += $r['cost'];                                                    }                                       ?>
          }

Comment: try this simpler approach, also you can just do it in your mysql query.

Comment: It's now working.... i understand this last query you sent. Thanks.

Comment: array_sum solution will work fine i just didn't tried it on playground but you need to pass first argument in array_column array not the object, well glad it worked for you :)

Comment: can you help me with this too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761817/how-can-i-display-a-query-from-an-individual-data-with-mulitple-data-in-mysql-ph

Comment: sure but your link is not accessible.